# Automatic destruction of static object

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

Why doesn't C++ create/destroy a static member of a template type.

Observe the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Dump {
  Dump() {
    std::cout << "CTOR" << std::endl;
  }
  ~Dump() {
    std::cout << "DTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename T> struct X {
  static Dump dump;
};

template <typename T> Dump X<T>::dump;

struct A : X<A> {
};

int main() {
  A a;
  return 0;
}
```

I would have expected that on execution I see the string `CTOR` followed by `DTOR`. While I don't. What am I missing here?

It has something to do with `dump` being the member of a template type, but that's as far as I get.

Comment: Where are you instantiating any of these types?

Comment: Do I actually have to? Anyway, `A` is instantiated in `main`, I'll edit.

Comment: @VJo: I tried to leave out what is not essential to the problem. Of course I have a `main`, see my edit (otherwise I could build an executable, now could I?).

Comment: Emmm. What behavior do you observe?

Comment: template <typename T> Dump X::dump; should be template <typename T> Dump X< T >::dump;

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for the hint, I must have overlooked it while copying stuff on to the site. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found something in **§ 14.7.1 Implicit instantiation**.

> **1/** [...] The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization **causes** the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but **not of** the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, **static data members** and member templates. [...]

It goes on in the second note:

> **2/** Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in particular, **the initialization** (and any associated side-effects) **of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used** in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

Therefore, unless you use it, *it should not be instantiated*. This is not an optimization, just Standard [n3092] conformance.

Answer (score 4):

It is not instantiated, unless used. This works :

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    (void) a.dump;
}
```

Also, fix the compilation error :

```
template <typename T> Dump X<T>::dump;
```

Comment: Thanks, now it does the trick. Man, **that's** what I call dangerous behaviour!

Comment: it looks more like optimization

Comment: You don't need to write `(void) a.dump`. Because `A a` will cause instantiation of the class template which in turn will create the static member instance.

Comment: @Nawaz: The entire point of the question is that `A` *does not*! At least not implicitly. What I did now is to mention the member in `A::A()`.

Comment: I was bitten by this once, and I learned. Just take it as it is (I looked into the standard, but couldn't find the relevant paragraphs)

Answer (score 4):

Members of class templates are only instantiated if they are needed; in this case, nothing refers to the static member, so it is not instantiated, even if the class template itself is.

You'll find that putting the statement `X<A>::dump;` somewhere will cause the member to be instantiated and an object created and destroyed.